# Extracting frequencies from multidimensional FFT

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I've written a python code to take a 2D signal and FFT it, and now I want to extract the frequencies associated with the FFT. The `np.fft.fftfreq` fails, giving me the error

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/helper.py", line 153, in fftfreq
    assert isinstance(n,types.IntType) or isinstance(n, integer)
AssertionError
```

My code is :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pylab
import sys
import math

filename = sys.argv[1]  # Get name of file to open 

ifp = open(filename, "r")
ifp.seek(0)

nrows = 0
ncols = 0

nrows = sum(1 for line in ifp) # Sum over all the lines in the file ptr

ifp.seek(0) # Set the fptr back to beginning of file
for line in ifp:
   ncols = len(line.split()) #Split and count number of words in a line
   if ncols > 0:
      break

OrigData = np.zeros([nrows, ncols], dtype=np.float32) #Allocate numpy array
FFTData = np.zeros([nrows, ncols], dtype=complex)
IFFTData = np.zeros([nrows, ncols], dtype=complex)
FreqComp = np.zeros([nrows, ncols], dtype=np.float32)

ii = 0
jj = 0
ifp.seek(0)
for line in ifp:
   linedata = line.split()
   jj = 0
   for el in linedata:
      OrigData[ii,jj] = float(el)
      jj+=1
   ii+=1
ifp.close()

FFTData = np.fft.fft2(OrigData)
FreqComp = np.fft.fftfreq(FFTData, d=2)

#--- Continue with more code ---#
```

I know that everything else works except the `np.fft.fftfreq` line, because I added that in last. How does one extract 2 dimensional frequency components?

Comment: See http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-August/022106.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are passing in an invalid parameter: `np.fft.fftfreq` takes the size of the signal data as first parameter (an integer) and the timestep as the second parameter. You are passing in an array as the first parameter.

You need to perform an `np.fft.fft` on the signal first though.

Hate to point out the obvious, but read [`np.fft.fftfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html)... the example code is very pretty clear.

---

Having performed a 2D FFT, you can obtain the sample frequencies along each dimension as follows:

```
FreqCompRows = np.fft.fftfreq(FFTData.shape[0],d=2)
FreqCompCols = np.fft.fftfreq(FFTData.shape[1],d=2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the line where I do the FFT. :P But how will this work for the 2d case? It'll return a 1d array of frequency components, I'm confused about how to interpret that.

Comment: are you using fft or fft2? ah, sorry, didn't notice your update.

Comment: `fft2`, they're all 2D arrays what I've defined.

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm confused about how to interpret that... If I have to figure out the frequency of a point on the 2D array, this method will give me two different frequencies, one for row and one for column. Will this be the frequency of the `x` and `y` component of the `sin` wave?

Comment: You seem to be having the same trouble as me visualising a 2D signal and its corresponding 2D frequency distribution. The best I can come up with at the moment is think of it as two orthogonal waves (like an EM field), so the 2D FFT will be the freq dist of each wave...

Comment: So I figured it out - The frequency corresponding to the row will be the `x` frequency of the `sin`, and the frequency corresponding to the column will be the `y` frequency of the `sin`. If there are two peaks with the same magnitude, it's just the real and complex part of the FFT, and they'll both correspond to the same frequency.