# Interpret numpy.fft.fft2 output

Tags: python, numpy, fft, frequency-distribution

My goal is to obtain a plot with the spatial frequencies of an image - kind of like doing a fourier transformation on it. I don't care about the position on the image of features with the frequency f (for instance); I'd just like to have a graphic which tells me how much of every frequency I have (the amplitude for a frequency band could be represented by the sum of contrasts with that frequency).

I am trying to do this via the [`numpy.fft.fft2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) function.

Here is a link to a [minimal example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/8606917/raw/2a93b8b1c3b15e8467cca21b5924c20533787fc5/imFreq?create=1) portraying my use case.

As it turns out I only get distinctly larger values for `frequencies[:30,:30]`, and of these the absolute highest value is `frequencies[0,0]`. How can I interpret this?

- What exactly does the amplitude of each value stand for?
- What does it mean that my highest value is in `frequency[0,0]` What is a `0 Hz` frequency?
- Can I bin the values somehow so that my frequency spectrum is orientation agnostic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding what a Fourier transform does (try http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I understand what a fft does in principle, I just don't really get the `numpy.fft.fft2` output, I would have expected a 1D array with no "null" frequency band.

Answer (score 13):

`freq` has a few very large values, and lots of small values. You can see that by plotting

```
plt.hist(freq.ravel(), bins=100)
```

(See below.) So, when you use

```
ax1.imshow(freq, interpolation="none")
```

Matplotlib uses `freq.min()` as the lowest value in the color range (which is by default colored blue), and `freq.max()` as the highest value in the color range (which is by default colored red). Since almost all the values in `freq` are near the blue end, the plot as a whole looks blue.

You can get a more informative plot by rescaling the values in `freq` so that the low values are more widely distributed on the color range.

For example, you can get a better distribution of values by taking the `log` of `freq`. (You probably don't want to throw away the highest values, since they correspond to frequencies with the highest power.)

```
import matplotlib as ml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import Image
file_path = "data"
image = np.asarray(Image.open(file_path).convert('L'))
freq = np.fft.fft2(image)
freq = np.abs(freq)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 6))
ax[0,0].hist(freq.ravel(), bins=100)
ax[0,0].set_title('hist(freq)')
ax[0,1].hist(np.log(freq).ravel(), bins=100)
ax[0,1].set_title('hist(log(freq))')
ax[1,0].imshow(np.log(freq), interpolation="none")
ax[1,0].set_title('log(freq)')
ax[1,1].imshow(image, interpolation="none")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html):

> The output, analogously to fft, contains the term for zero frequency
>   in the low-order corner of the transformed axes,

Thus, `freq[0,0]` is the "zero frequency" term. In other words, it is the constant term in the [discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition).

Comment: `freq.ravel()` unravels the 2d array into a 1d array whereby each row is read consecutively - right? how come I don't get a second peak at 200, a third at 400 etc (as the log(freq) plot would indicate)? Also, why does hist(log(freq)) stop at 16 on the x-axis?

Comment: `plt.hist` is making a histogram of the values. The `x-axis` represents values of `log(freq)` and the `y-axis` represents a count of how freqently those values occur. There are no repetitive peaks because similar values are being binned together. The upper value of `16` means that the largest value in `log(freq)` is near 16. Indeed, `np.log(freq.max())` equals 14.8.

Comment: (And yes, `freq.ravel()` is a 1D view of the 2D array.)

Comment: got it ;) and what spatial frequency (as measured in 1/px) does the value in freq[0,1] for instance correspond to?

Comment: You could use [numpy.fft.fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) for that. There is a 2D example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14583370/190597).

Comment: so the actual information about what frequency each pixel corresponds to is not included in the np.fft.fft2 output?

Comment: Right. The `freq` variable is holding DFT coefficients. (Yeah, the variable name should probably be changed.) The *location* of the coefficient in the array indicates the frequency.

Comment: right - so if a coefficient is at position freq[0,1], what frequency does that indicate?

Comment: There are two frequencies associated with `freq[0,1]`: The frequency in the `x-direction`, and the frequency in the `y-direction`. The frequencies would be given by `np.fft.fftfreq(image.shape[0])[0], np.fft.fftfreq(image.shape[1])[1]`. Reading [this](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/npdoc/reference/routines.fft.html) might help too.

Comment: what is `freq` contains 0 and `log(freq)` gives `-Inf`?