# Get a spatial frequency breakdown for greyscale image (2d array)

Tags: python, numpy, fft, frequency-distribution

I would like to get a plot of how much each spatial frequency is present in a grayscale image.

I have been told to try `np.fft.fft2` but apparently this is not what I need (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362843/interpret-numpy-fft-fft2-output)). I was then told to look into `np.fft.fftfreq` - and while that *sounds* like what I need it will only take an integer as input, so

```
np.fft.fftfreq(np.fft.fft2(image))
```

won't work. Nor does:

```
np.fft.fftfreq(np.abs(np.fft.fft2(image)))
```

How else could I try to do this? it seems like a rather trivial task for a fourier transform. It's actually *the* task of the fourier transform. I don't understand why `np.fft.fft2` doesn't have a flag to make the frequency analysis orientation-agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should reread the comments in the linked question, as well as the documentation also posted in the last comment. You are supposed to pass the image shape to `np.fft.fftfreq`:

```
freqx = np.fft.fftfreq(image.shape[0])
```

for x-direction and

```
freqy = np.fft.fftfreq(image.shape[1])
```

for y-direction.

The results will be the centers of the frequency bins returned by `fft2`, for example:

```
image_fft = np.fft.fft2(image)
```

Then the frequency corresponding to the amplitude `image_fft[i,j]` is `freqx[i]` in x-direction and `freqy[i]` in y-direction.

Your last sentence indicates that you want to do something completely different, though. The Fourier transform of a two-dimensional input is by common definition also two-dimensional. What deviating definition do you want to use?

Comment: So to get the orientation agnostic frequency for `image_fft[i,j]` I would do `np.sqrt(freqx[i]^2+freqy[j]^2)`? how can I get an array with all the amplitudes of all frequencies without having to iterate over tens of millions of values? (this is what my last sentence was referring to).

Comment: 1. `^` should be `**`. In python `^` is bitwise XOR. 2. I'm not sure, whether this makes any sense in any context. 3. Iteration in python is pretty simple and if you want to reduce dimensions you need to iterate anyway to perform the reduction for example by averaging. I am still not sure what exactly your desired output is. It would help if you could provide the mathematical formula.

Comment: my desired output is a 2xN array where N is the number of discrete frequencies. [0,N] should correspond to the frequencies and [1,N] to the amplitudes of the respective frequencies. I want to plot a graphic which looks like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013b/matlab/math/periodogram2.gif). This should be the most basic and commonplace thing fft is used for. Why does nobody seem to understand this?